# Changing table name from upper to lower case

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I alter a table name in upper case to lower case? Would it be reflected in its references also?

My project is already done.

Answer (score 1):

If the database collation is case-insensitive then it could be changed, I'd check the server collation, too just in case.

```
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases.
```

CI indicates case-insensitive, CS is case sensitive. If you right click the server in SSMS and check properties you'll see the server collation name in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what David said, changing the table name, even just to change the casing, won't update your objects that reference that table in a query. I.e. any views, procedures, functions, etc, would still have the original casing in their definitions.

If your database and server are case-insensitive, this won't affect anything functionally, and the database objects that reference that table will still to continue to work.

To rename a table, you can use SSMS and right click it, then click Rename or you can use the system procedure [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).